# Jeditable - highlight all text after double click

Tags: jquery, jeditable

is there any options on jeditble so when i double click my text and the textbox pops up that it highlights all of the text

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the select parameter. True means select (highlight all). False is the opposite.

```
$(".editable").editable("http://www.example.com/save.php", { 
    type   : "textarea",
    select : true
});
```

Answer (score 2):

for doubleclick:

```
$(".editable").editable("http://www.example.com/save.php", { 
 type   : "textarea",
 event  : "dblclick",
 select : true
});
```